# Label that counts chars under textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this textarea in my view where i can enter text:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => model.text, new { @class = "form-control", style = "text-align: center" })
```

I would like to add a label below the textArea that counts the chars(including whitespace). Ideally it would be great if I could enter a number and let the counter count down from that number.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I would like a label that decreases by 1 for each char entered in the textArea.

Answer (score 1):

My *snippet* its a complete pure **HTML/Javascript** solution(not tested very well, I'm sorry), this is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/YZ9s2/), I think you need only a bunch of *javascript* to achieve your task. Missing the management of *Canc*, only single keypress are managed.
What are you looking for its something like this?

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .counter{
            display:block;
            height:5px;
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <textarea class="target"></textarea>
        <span class="counter"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            var oldCount = 0;
            var $area = $('.target');
            var $label = $('.counter');

            $label.css('width', $area.width());

            $area.on('keyup', function () {
                var currentCount = $area.val().length;
                if (currentCount > oldCount && currentCount > 0) {
                    $label.width($label.width() - 10);
                }
                else if (currentCount < oldCount && $label.width() < $area.width())
                {
                    $label.width($label.width() + 10);
                }
                oldCount = currentCount;
            });
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes it´s something like that im looking for. Also found some similar code here:
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-wordtext-counter-plugins/